# Zoho Bill "tax_type" field on REST endpoint

Tags: json, rest, zoho

When working with bill items through the REST API, there is a field called `tax_type` on the response body that seems to (at least to me) always return with `tax` as its value.

I thought that a tax could be classified as inclusive or exclusive (as in the tax is included on the item's price or is to be charged separately).

Any ideas on what this field means?

A JSON sample can be seen at https://www.zoho.com/books/api/v3/#Bills_Get_a_bill

Comment: Could you post complete json and api end point?

Comment: You can see an example on https://www.zoho.com/books/api/v3/#Bills_Get_a_bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Zoho Books, taxes can be either simple tax (`tax`) or compound tax (`compound_tax`) or tax groups (`tax_groups`). In Settings -> Taxes, You can create these type of taxes.

If you associate `compound tax` to the bill, you will get the `tax_type` as `compound_tax`.

PS: `is_inclusive_tax` node is used to find the bill is either inclusive or exclusive.